# Adding column to dataframe based on column's values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to add a column based on existing column values matching with a dataframe with a different length.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

    a = DataFrame([['a', '1'], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]], columns=['Letters', 'Numbers'])
    b = DataFrame([['a', '2001'], ['b', '2002'], ['c', '2003'], ['d', '2004']], columns=['Letters', 'Years'])
```

How can I add a column to **a** called **Years** which has the year where **Letters** of **a** and **b** match.

Desired output:

```
df = DataFrame([['a', '1', '2001'], ['b', 2, '2002'], ['c', 3, '2003']], columns=['Letters', 'Numbers', 'Years'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), if joined column is same in both `DataFrame`, parameter `on` can be omited, also by default is `inner` join, so parameter `how` is omit too:

```
print (pd.merge(a,b))
  Letters Numbers Years
0       a       1  2001
1       b       2  2002
2       c       3  2003
```

---

```
print (pd.merge(a,b, on='Letters'))
  Letters Numbers Years
0       a       1  2001
1       b       2  2002
2       c       3  2003
```

Comment: Happy holidays:-)

Comment: Thank you very much, for you too ;)